# Webpack - manually create async commons chunk

Tags: javascript, webpack

In Webpack, how would I go about creating a normal (non-entry), async chunk which contains only the content I specify.

For example, let's say I have `moduleA` and `moduleB`. Both are loaded on-demand through `System.import`.  `moduleA` and `moduleB` both use various contents in the `/shared` directory.  How would I go about creating an async chunk containing (only) **all** the contents in shared?  (in real life there'd be more than just `moduleA` and `moduleB` sharing stuff in `shared`)

The closest [the docs](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin) seem to show is the `chunks` array, but that seems to be the chunks to analyze for common content, which will be extracted into the common chunk.

This question is an extension of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35514785/webpack-2-code-splitting-top-level-dependencies/36590429#36590429) (written by the Webpack creator no less).

I'm just wondering how (if possible) you can take greater, more fine-grained control over **what** goes into your common chunks, by specifying *manually* what goes *into* them.

Comment: The DllPlugin sounds a _bit_ like what you want, except that I'm not sure about the async loading aspect.  Have you looked at that at all?  If not, I've got several links to articles about the DllPlugin at https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/webpack-advanced-techniques.md.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This plugin moves all modules from `shared` that are used from at least two on-demand-loaded chunks with a common parent into a separate async commons chunk.

You can optionally pass a `name` parameter, if you know the common parent chunk (i. e. the router).

```
new CommonsChunkPlugin({
  async: true,
  children: true,
  minChunks: function(module, count) {
    return module.resource &&
      module.resource.indexOf("/path/to/shared/") === 0 &&
      count >= 2;
  }
})
```